# Prove that $f(n) = n^2 - 1$ is not injective and not surjective. Am I doing it right?

Tags: proof-writing

Determine if $f(n) = n^2 - 1$ is injective, surjective, and prove your answer.

The domain and codomain is the set of all integers: $\mathbb{Z}$

Let $-3 = n^2 - 1$

Then $n = \sqrt{-2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore f$ is not surjective.

Let $f(n) = 3$

Then $f(2) = 2^2 - 1 = 3$ and $f(-2) = (-2)^2 - 1 = 3$

$\therefore f$ is not injective. $\square$

Comment: Looks solid to me. Did you have any questions?

Comment: Do I have to prove it is a function first? It seems like a dumb question, but thought I would ask anyways.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to me if the question is already asking you to prove or disprove injectivity/surjectivity.

Comment: You have to see it is a function first, (if it isn't a function it can't be injective or surjective) but you don't need to write a proof for it.

Comment: Thanks, it helps to know I am not leaving anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write something like $\sqrt{-2}\not\in \mathbb{Z}$. Just write that $-2=n^2$ has no solution.
The let $f(n)=3$ is not good too, since you could think this is true for any $n$.

Comment: So what should I say "choose" $f(n) = 3$ instead?

Comment: Na just say, $f(2)=3$  (with calculation) and $f(-2)=3$ so it can't be injective

Comment: @Leonardo: Simply show that $f(2)=f(-2)$ and point out that particularly, $2\neq-2$.